# Copy Large Result Set From SQL Server to Redis or a NoSql Database

Tags: mongodb, caching, sql-server-2008-r2, ravendb, nosql

We have a large table in SQL Server (100+ million rows) that we would like to export to either Redis or another NoSQL database like RavenDB or MongoDB for efficient caching.

We would like this export to happen once or twice a day.

What would be the best way to do this and make sure that both SQL Server and the caching layer does not experience performance issues at the time of the process.

Note we are C# developers but do not have the option of using NServiceBus.

Comment: 100 million rows of what? A single byte or 15mb binary blobs?

Comment: About 300 MB total - mostly varchars